# Testing a Android Broadcast Receiver for SMS

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I have written a SMSReceiver for Android and all works fine on real devices and when I test the App over Telnet.

But how can I create a unit test for the following *onReceive* Method in Android Studio?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle!=null){
        Object[] smsExtras = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        String format = (String)bundle.get("format");
        String strMessage = "";

        for (Object smsExtra : smsExtras) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
                smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra);
            }else {
                smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra, format);
            }

            String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            String messageSource = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

            strMessage += "SMS from " + messageSource + " : " + messageBody;
            Log.i(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, strMessage);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can't write unit test cases here as you need context in onReceive

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to test, but it looks like you want to check that the message body and address is correctly parsed and has the expected contents. In that case you can break out that logic into a separate method and unit test it, by passing in a PDU and checking the return value.

If you want to test onReceive, it should be possible to use Mockito, pass in a MockContext and mock Intent's getExtra to return your own test Bundle object. Still, you'll need to verify something in the end. Perhaps you're planning to store the parsed data somewhere later? If so you can use that as your verification point - either by capturing and checking the argument, or verifying that the data was stored (though that's stretching the boundaries of the unit test quite a bit).